# Fill column with prior nonmissing value, no ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to fill a missing ID column of a data frame as shown below. It's not blank in the first row it applies to and then blank until the next ID. I wrote ugly code to do this in a `for` loop, but wonder if there's a tidy-ier way to do this. Any suggestions?

Here's what I've got:

```
   code data
1     A    1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
6          6
7          7
8          8
9          9
10        10
11    B   11
12        12
13        13
14        14
15        15
16    C   16
17        17
18        18
19        19
20        20
```

I want:

```
   code data
1     A    1
2     A    2
3     A    3
4     A    4
5     A    5
6     A    6
7     A    7
8     A    8
9     A    9
10    A   10
11    B   11
12    B   12
13    B   13
14    B   14
15    B   15
16    C   16
17    C   17
18    C   18
19    C   19
20    C   20
```

Code I've got now:

```
# Create mock data frame
df <- data.frame(code = c("A", rep("", 9), 
                          "B", rep("", 4), 
                          "C", rep("", 4)), 
                 data = 1:20)

# For loop over rows (BAD!)
for (i in seq(2, nrow(df))) {
  df[i,]$code <- ifelse(df[i,]$code == "", df[i-1,]$code, df[i, ]$code)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `tidyr` way to do it, there is the `fill` function.  You also need to replace the zero length string with `NA` for this to work, which you can easily do using the `mutate` and `na_if` functions from `dplyr`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(code = na_if(code,"")) %>% 
  fill(code)

   code data
1     A    1
2     A    2
3     A    3
4     A    4
5     A    5
6     A    6
7     A    7
8     A    8
9     A    9
10    A   10
11    B   11
12    B   12
13    B   13
14    B   14
15    B   15
16    C   16
17    C   17
18    C   18
19    C   19
20    C   20
```